Electric Field of a Linear Electric Quadrupole Along x Axis
A charge $+q$ is at $x=-d$. Another $+q$ is at $x=+d$ and $-2q$ is at the origin. a) Derive expressions for the electric field along the x-axis as a function of x. b) show that $E∝\frac{1}{r^4}$ for $x$ much greater than $d$.
Part a:
$E_1=\frac{kq}{(x-d)^2}, E_2=\frac{-2kq}{x^2}, E_3=\frac{kq}{(x+d)^2}$
$E_t=kq(\frac{1}{(x-d)^2}+\frac{1}{(x+d)^2}-\frac{2}{x^2})$
Part b: ???
How am I supposed to get to $kq.\frac{something}{x^4}$ ?
I managed to get to the answer for the y-axis which is perpendicular with the help of this link but not the x-axis.

It is not completely clear to me if you want the electric field on the $x$-axis with $x \gg d$, or if the point does not need to be on the $x$-axis, as long as $x \gg d$.
I suspect it is the first case.
Having answered part a), you are half-way through.
I would suggest simplifying the expression for $Et$ that you found, writing it as
$$
  Et
  = k q \frac{2 d^2 (3 x^2 - d^2)}{x^2 \left(x^2-d^2\right)^2}.
$$
At this point, either you expand this expression in Taylor series around $d=0$ (you will need to go up to the second order) or, just by looking at this expression and using the fact that $x \gg d$, you can find the solution since
$$
  a x^2 - d^2 \approx a x^2
$$
for any coefficient $a$ which is of order unity.

Thanks a lot! So the trick was in the simplification.

@TEGNO I would say that the trick was in the expansion, but the simplification helped.
